# IdentityServer4 RequireConsent true hangs

Tags: identityserver4

I setup IdentityServer4 following IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity tutorial. 
If i set RequireConsent = true on client settings, redirect to url hangs.
Any suggestions?

```
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    { return new List<Client> {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "MyUx",
                ClientName = "MyUx MVC Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                RequireConsent = false,
                ClientSecrets= {new Secret("abcdef".Sha256()) },

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },

                PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5002"},

                AllowedScopes = {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,

                    "custom.profile"                     
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }
        };
```

}
Thanks and regards

Comment: Do you have a consent page?

Comment: That was my mistake. Sorry, missed that :-/

Comment: Hi @ozgurozkanakdemirci you question is still open but it does not make sense once you already solved the problem. I think you could add the answer saying that the solution was only add a consent page and then close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was only adding a consent page when RequireConsent = true
Thanks @leastprivilege